# Failed Mysql Insert Query

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm getting the following error Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1683

```
INSERT INTO `r10_pull`(`id`, `r10_database_id2`, `repName`, `dateRequested`, `addresspulled`, `status`, `emailAddress`, `type`, `streetStartType`, `streetStartName`, `streetStartDir`, `streetStartCiv`, `streetEndType`, `streetEndName`, `streetEndDir`, `streetEndCiv`, `reportNode`, `systemName`) VALUES ('','$r10_database_id2','$rep','$todaysdate','$address','0','$repemail','$type','$street[streetStartType]','$street[streetStartName]','$street[streetStartDir]','$street[streetStartCiv]','$street[streetEndType]','$street[streetEndName]','$street[streetEndDir]','$street[streetEndCiv]','$reportNode','$systemName')
```

Comment: use single quote for all string values.

Comment: Remove the first comma in `VALUES` ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's in desperate need of [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: The reason I have the first comma is I want the first value to be blank. i have tried using single quotes '' but have had no luck

Comment: Also remove the bracket after $systemName.

Comment: If you want the first value to be blank. Put `'',` .

Comment: Make your life easier and use prepared statements or PDO.

Comment: Changing your code midstream (from what's been posted below) without showing as an edit deserves a -1 as well as a vote to clear as unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many typos -
1) Put empty string in place of 1st empty `,` in values

2) Remove `]` from last value

3) Also needed single quotes in string values

You have got 18 `column` name and now after removing typos got 18 values

```
INSERT INTO `r10_pull`(`id`, `r10_database_id2`, `repName`, `dateRequested`,   `addresspulled`, `status`, `emailAddress`, `type`, `streetStartType`, `streetStartName`, `streetStartDir`, `streetStartCiv`, `streetEndType`, `streetEndName`, `streetEndDir`, `streetEndCiv`, `reportNode`, `systemName`) 
VALUES ('','$r10_database_id2','$rep','$todaysdate','$address',0,'$repemail','$type','$street[streetStartType]','$street[streetStartName]','$street[streetStartDir]','$street[streetStartCiv]','$street[streetEndType]','$street[streetEndName]','$street[streetEndDir]','$street[streetEndCiv]','$reportNode','$systemName')
```

**Suggestions:** Above is the direct answer to your question. Still avoid using mysql_* function as they are deprecated. Learn mysqli or PDO and start implementing.

Using `mysqli_* prepared function` -

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'mysampledb');

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `r10_pull` (`id`, `r10_database_id2`, `repName`, `dateRequested`,   `addresspulled`, `status`, `emailAddress`, `type`, `streetStartType`, `streetStartName`, `streetStartDir`, `streetStartCiv`, `streetEndType`, `streetEndName`, `streetEndDir`, `streetEndCiv`, `reportNode`, `systemName`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssssssss', <-- all 18 variables with comma seperated-->);   // bind $sample to the parameter

/* execute prepared statement */  
$stmt->execute();

printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

/* close statement and connection */
$stmt->close();

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: You're welcome. I removed my downvote. However, this is still open to SQL injection so I will not be upvoting (*till then*).

Comment: FYI: It seems like the OP has just changed/edited his/her code (now) to be as you have it. I would ask the OP to show full code.

Comment: mysqli_* prepared example given.

Comment: I saw that Parag which is good, however the OP's question still remains unclear until we see full code including DB schema. I voted to close the question as unclear. If OP accepts your answer, I will upvote. I can't speak for the OP on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
INSERT INTO `r10_pull`(`id`, `r10_database_id2`, `repName`, `dateRequested`, `addresspulled`, `status`, `emailAddress`, `type`, `streetStartType`, `streetStartName`, `streetStartDir`, `streetStartCiv`, `streetEndType`, `streetEndName`, `streetEndDir`, `streetEndCiv`, `reportNode`, `systemName`) 
VALUES ('',$r10_database_id2,$rep,$todaysdate,$address,0,$repemail,$type,$street['streetStartType'],$street['streetStartName'],$street['streetStartDir'],$street['streetStartCiv'],$street['streetEndType'],$street['streetEndName'],$street['streetEndDir'],$street['streetEndCiv'],$reportNode,$systemName);
```

Comment: I removed my downvote because the OP changed his/her code after the fact.